# Write dataframe groupby id and date into a one csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73734634/10309712) on dynamicallay creating sub-folders and writing files to sub-folders, I realised I needed further help, having applied to real dataset.

Suppose this is the dataframe that I have:

```py
data = {'user': [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11], 
 'session_id': [15, 15, 15, 15, 31, 31, 31, 20, 20,
                 20, 43, 43, 43], 
 'logtime': ['2016-04-13 07:58:40', '2016-04-13 07:58:41','2016-04-13 07:58:42',
             '2016-04-13 07:58:43', '2016-04-01 20:29:37', '2016-04-01 20:29:42', 
             '2016-04-01 20:29:47', '2016-04-13 21:04:27', '2016-04-13 21:04:28', 
             '2016-04-13 21:04:29', '2016-03-30 06:21:59', '2016-03-30 06:22:04', 
             '2016-03-30 06:22:09'], 
 'lat': [41.1872084, 41.1870716, 41.1869719, 41.1868664, 41.1471521, 41.1472466, 
          41.1473038, 40.0121007, 40.0121084, 40.0121534, 41.2372125, 41.2371444, 41.2369725], 
 'lon': [-8.6038931, -8.6037318, -8.6036908, -8.6036423, -8.5878757, -8.5874314, -8.586632, 
         -8.5992162, -8.5992024, -8.5991788, -8.6720773, -8.6721269, -8.6718833]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
    user    session_id  logtime               lat          lon
0   7            15    2016-04-13 07:58:40  41.187208   -8.603893
1   7            15    2016-04-13 07:58:41  41.187072   -8.603732
2   7            15    2016-04-13 07:58:42  41.186972   -8.603691
3   7            15    2016-04-13 07:58:43  41.186866   -8.603642
4   7            31    2016-04-01 20:29:37  41.147152   -8.587876
5   7            31    2016-04-01 20:29:42  41.147247   -8.587431
6   7            31    2016-04-01 20:29:47  41.147304   -8.586632
7   7            20    2016-04-13 21:04:27  40.012101   -8.599216
8   7            20    2016-04-13 21:04:28  40.012108   -8.599202
9   7            20    2016-04-13 21:04:29  40.012153   -8.599179
10  11           43    2016-03-30 06:21:59  41.237212   -8.672077
11  11           43    2016-03-30 06:22:04  41.237144   -8.672127
12  11           43    2016-03-30 06:22:09  41.236973   -8.671883
```

I am re-organising this dataframe by creating sub-folder for each user. And then creating a `CSV` file in that user sub-folder. The file should contain user's session log,`logtime, lat, lon`.  However, I want to write sessions I user covered in the same day into 1 file like `file1.csv`.

This answer to my previous question is fine:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', parse_dates=['logtime'])

# make base dir
base_folder = 'Data'
os.makedirs(base_folder, exist_ok=True)

for user_id, user_data in df.groupby('user'):
    user_folder = f'{base_folder}/{user_id}'
    os.makedirs(user_folder, exist_ok=True)

    for file_id, (sess_id, data) in enumerate(user_data.groupby(['session_id'])):
        filename = f'{user_folder}/file{file_id + 1}.csv'
        data.drop(['user', 'session_id'], axis=1).to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Which creates 1 file for each session of a user, resulting in dir structure:

```
$ tree  Data/
Data/
├── 11
│   └── file1.csv
└── 7
    ├── file1.csv
    ├── file2.csv
    └── file3.csv

2 directories, 4 files
```

File contents:

```
$ cat Data/7/file1.csv 
logtime,lat,lon
2016-04-13 07:58:40,41.1872084,-8.6038931
2016-04-13 07:58:41,41.1870716,-8.6037318
2016-04-13 07:58:42,41.1869719,-8.6036908
2016-04-13 07:58:43,41.1868664,-8.6036423

$ cat Data/7/file2.csv 
logtime,lat,lon
2016-04-13 21:04:27,40.0121007,-8.5992162
2016-04-13 21:04:28,40.0121084,-8.5992024
2016-04-13 21:04:29,40.0121534,-8.5991788

$ cat Data/7/file3.csv 
logtime,lat,lon
2016-04-01 20:29:37,41.1471521,-8.5878757
2016-04-01 20:29:42,41.1472466,-8.5874314
2016-04-01 20:29:47,41.1473038,-8.586632
```

Since session `15` and `20` of user `7` were covered in one day, I would combined these into `file1.csv` altogether, maintaining the time order (logs of session `15` then `20`).

To do this, I modified the code above to:

```py
for ..
     # now group by 'session_id', 'logtime'
    for file_id, (sess_id, data) in enumerate(user_data.groupby(['session_id', 'logtime'])):
        filename = f'{user_folder}/file{file_id + 1}.csv'
        data.drop(['user', 'session_id'], axis=1).to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Giving:

```py
$ tree Data/
Data/
├── 11
│   ├── file1.csv
│   ├── file2.csv
│   └── file3.csv
└── 7
    ├── file10.csv
    ├── file1.csv
    ├── file2.csv
    ├── file3.csv
    ├── file4.csv
    ├── file5.csv
    ├── file6.csv
    ├── file7.csv
    ├── file8.csv
    └── file9.csv

2 directories, 13 files
```

Creating 1 file for each row of user `7`.

**Required:**

```
$ tree  Data/
Data/
├── 11
│   └── file1.csv
|   |       2016-03-30 06:21:59,41.237212,-8.672077
|   |       2016-03-30 06:22:04,41.237144,-8.672127
|   |       2016-03-30 06:22:09,41.236973,-8.671883
└── 7
    ├── file1.csv
    |       2016-04-13 07:58:40,41.187208,-8.603893
    |       2016-04-13 07:58:41,41.187072,-8.603732
    |       2016-04-13 07:58:42,41.186972,-8.603691
    |       2016-04-13 07:58:43,41.186866,-8.603642
    |       2016-04-13 21:04:27,40.012101,-8.599216
    |       2016-04-13 21:04:28,40.012108,-8.599202
    |       2016-04-13 21:04:29,40.012153,-8.599179
    └── file2.csv
            2016-04-01 20:29:37,41.147152,-8.587876
            2016-04-01 20:29:42,41.147247,-8.587431
            2016-04-01 20:29:47,41.147304,-8.586632

2 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: Am I right, that you don't know the session_id after creating your tree with the files in it ? (and also don't need then?)

Comment: Yes, that's not required after the operation.

Comment: Your mistake here was that you grouped by `session_id, logtime`... `logtime` are all unique times, so each single line in your data is considered its own group. which is handled one by one each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. You can't combine two sessions at one day  because you groupby `session_id` so in each iteration you only can handle one session. Since you are only interested in sessions that took place at the same day, groupby the day in the 2nd step.

```py
base_folder = 'Data'
os.makedirs(base_folder, exist_ok=True)

for user_id, user_data in df.groupby('user'):
    user_folder = f'{base_folder}/{user_id}'
    os.makedirs(user_folder, exist_ok=True)
    
    for file_id, (sess_id, data) in enumerate(user_data.groupby(user_data['logtime'].dt.date)):
        filename = f'{user_folder}/file{file_id + 1}.csv'
        data.drop(['user', 'session_id'], axis=1).to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Comment: Right! This works as intended. Many thanks.